# Open source code based on quandl for security analysis and options priming

Tags: option-pricing, time-series, quantlib, technical-analysis, opensource

Quandl seems to be an excellent source of wide range of free/open financial data. But is there an open source code or platform that uses the quandl datasets to perform security analysis and option pricing.

Answer (score 2):

This [Quandl Page](https://www.quandl.com/tools/full-list) provides you the informations you need: a lot of programming languages and other tools are linked to Quandl.